# How to start up qpaeq on boot without gui

Tags: pulseaudio

I recently installed pulse audio eq but when I start up my system the eq doesn't start as well and I have to run qpaeq for it to show up in my audio outputs. I could just add qpaeq to startup but I don't want the gui to open whenever I log in so is there a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

`qpaeq` only works when you have the modules installed. You only need to add it to the configuration files. [From the pulseaudio wiki for arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio#Equalization):

> To load the equalizer and dbus module on every boot, edit the `/etc/pulse/default.pa` or `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` file with your favorite editor and append the following lines:
>
> ```
>    ### Load the integrated PulseAudio equalizer and D-Bus module
>    load-module module-equalizer-sink
>    load-module module-dbus-protocol
> ```